# Building string from variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In a chef environment, for a cookbook, I have these arrays:

```
"envs": ["ci","ui","qa"],
"services": ["service_a","service_b","service_c","service_x"]
```

In the template file I'm using this:

```
<% @envs.each do |env| %>
file {
  <%
    logfiles = ""
    @services.each do |service|
      logfiles = logfiles + "\"" + "/remotelogs/" + @env + "/" + @service + "_syslog.log\", "
    end
    logfiles = logfiles.chomp(", ")
  %>
  path           => [<%= logfiles %>]    
}
 <% end %>
```

The error I get is this:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
...
Template Context:
-----------------
on line #7
  5:       logfiles = ""
  6:       @services.each do |service|
  7:         logfiles = logfiles + "\"" + "/remotelogs/" + @env + "/" + @service + "_syslog.log\", "
  8:       end
  9:         logfiles = logfiles.chomp(", ")
 (erubis):7:in `+'
 (erubis):7:in `block (3 levels) in evaluate'
 (erubis):6:in `each'
 (erubis):6:in `block (2 levels) in evaluate'
 (erubis):2:in `each'
 (erubis):2:in `block in evaluate'
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm guessing that I did not escape very good the quotation marks?

The final result should be something like three rows (one per environment) and for each, the path should have the value:

```
path           => ["/remotelogs/ci/service_a_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ci/service_b_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ci/service_c_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ci/service_x_syslog.log"]
```

Answer (score 5):

In this line

```
logfiles = logfiles + "\"" + "/remotelogs/" + @env + "/" + @service + "_syslog.log\", "
```

should be `env`, not `@env`. Note that same is for `service`. This is better

```
logfiles += "\"/remotelogs/#{env}/#{service}_syslog.log\", "
```

Or if you don't want to escape the double quotes, you can use [percent string literals](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation):

```
logfiles += %{"/remotelogs/#{env}/#{service}_syslog.log", }
```

Comment: You also can use the percent string literal so that you don't have to escape the double quotes: `%{"/remotelogs/#{env}/#{service}_syslog.log"} #=> "\"/remotelogs/ci/service_a_syslog.log\""`

Comment: I'm sorry Michael, I don't know that. Do you want to edit my answer? :)

Comment: Done. Also included a doc link.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your code correctly, you're trying to reimplement [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-join) but all you need is [`inspect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-inspect) :

```
@envs = ["ci","ui","qa"]
@services = ["service_a","service_b","service_c","service_x"]

@envs.each do |env|
  logfiles = @services.map{|service|
    "/remotelogs/#{env}/#{service}_syslog.log"
  }
  puts logfiles.inspect
end
```

It outputs :

```
["/remotelogs/ci/service_a_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ci/service_b_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ci/service_c_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ci/service_x_syslog.log"]
["/remotelogs/ui/service_a_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ui/service_b_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ui/service_c_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/ui/service_x_syslog.log"]
["/remotelogs/qa/service_a_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/qa/service_b_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/qa/service_c_syslog.log", "/remotelogs/qa/service_x_syslog.log"]
```

Adapted to your ERB template, it becomes :

```
<% @envs.each do |env| %>
file {
  <%
    logfiles = @services.map{|service|
      "/remotelogs/#{env}/#{service}_syslog.log"
    }
  %>
  path           => <%= logfiles.inspect %>
}
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you all. It's fixed now.